# Population or populations?

Tags: terminology, grammaticality

Is this paragraph correct in its usage of "population"?

> The 100 million *population* in the Philippines is ranked 12th in the world and projected to grow 1.89% per year. The emerging middle class range of the *populations* are bound to drive forward the beauty trade industry in the Philippines.

Comment: The element of concern is identified in the question, so this doesn't appear to be a "Where are the mistakes" proof-reading question.

Answer (score 2):

The paragraph is not correct in its usage of "population". The first sentence is incorrect, as it should be "**[population of the country](http://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=2079)**" not "population **in** the country". "Population" should be used throughout here, not "populations".

In order to refer to specific aspects of the Philippines archipelago, especially if stratified by socioeconomic class and industry, it is necessary to explicitly break out the details. For example, "population data **for** rural areas" or "population **by** island" could be correct. "Populations" is unlikely to be correct. "Sub-group" or "segment" of the population is used instead.

The passage provided could be re-written like this, for grammatical correctness:

> The population of the Philippines is 100 million, ranked 12th in the
>   world and projected to grow by 1.89% per year. The emerging middle
>   class segment of the population is certain to drive forward the beauty trade
>   industry in the Philippines.

This sort of writing is common in the field of **demographics**. The OECD has a helpful, free **[demographics style guide](http://stats.oecd.org/glossary/about.asp)**.

Answer (score 1):

The Philippines is an archipelago, each inhabited island of which has its local population. So in this particular case, *populations* could be justified on geographical grounds.

The context of the text from which this fragment has been ripped may further clarify the intention of the writer in using the plural form of the noun.

(Incidentally, "emerging **middle class range** of the populations" is hardly the most felicitous formulation ever concocted.)

Comment: The first sentence treats the country as a single entity. It seems inconsistent to switch modes in the second sentence with no justification.

Comment: @Barmar - You make a very reasonable point. No-one could accuse this piece of being well-written.

Answer (score 0):

The writer has considered Phillipines as an UNIT in the first sentence and thus used the conventional word "population".

The second sentence `emerging middle class range of the populations` appears to be an attempt to differentiate/highlight the variety in the Filipino population.
But the writing is **incoherent**.

Some online references to **populations**:

Researchers often work with a variety of populations.

Sometimes the common conventions of language inadvertently contain biases towards certain populations.

Are there meaningful similarities among the literatures of different post-colonial populations?

Source: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/722/10/

Answer (score 0):

The population of the Philippines is 100 million, ranked 12th in the world and projected to grow 1.89% per year, of which the emerging middle class are bound to drive forward the local trade industry.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).